# visitor pattern in PHP

Tags: php

I was asked this interview question recently:

> "Which PHP mechanism allows to use visitor pattern to sort an array?".

I am not sure what mechanism we have in PHP? Can anyone provide an example of its use as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is:

In the Visitor pattern, one class calls a function in another class with the current instance of itself. The called class has special functions for each class that can call it.

Accorting to php docs:

**uasort** — Sort an array with a user-defined comparison function and maintain index association

```
uasort($collection, array('MyClassName', 'mySortMethod'));
```

Comment: either this, or custom abstract/extended classes to implement the sorting

Comment: uasort() is a correct answer, the conecpt is mainly used in JAVA not in PHP, so it's wierd that they've asked you about that in interview.